# Invariance of Wave Equation under Lorentz Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the wave operator

$$ \Box f = \partial_t^2 f - \Delta_x f. $$

If $Q(t,x) = t^2 - |x|^2$, then $\Box = Q(\partial_t, D_x)$. Now if we change variables, writing $(s,y) = A \cdot (t,x)$ for some matrix $A$, then the change of variables formula implies that $(\partial_s, D_y) = A^t \cdot (\partial_t, D_x)$. In particular, this means that $Q(\partial_t, D_x) = Q(\partial_s, D_y)$ provided that $Q(A^t (\partial_t, D_x)) = Q(\partial_t, D_x)$, i.e. if $B$ is the linear transform given by $B(t,x) = (t,-x)$, then this occurs if and only if $ABA^T = B$. On the other hand, the class of Lorentz transforms is precisely the family of linear maps $A$ such that $Q(A(t,x)) = Q(t,x)$, i.e. such that $A^T B A = B$. It therefore seems to be the case that $\Box$ is preserved by linear transforms whose *transpose* is a Lorentz transform. But many books claim that the wave operator is invariant under the family of Lorentz transforms, not the family of transposes of Lorentz transforms. What part of this calculation is incorrect, or if it is correct, am I misunderstanding what it means for the wave operator to be invariant under a Lorentz transform?

Comment: The transpose of a Lorentz transformation is a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: How does one see this?